# ServiceStack.OrmLite: Support for sql native JSON types and indexing?

Tags: c#, mysql, json, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Our current data model has sub-objects, something like

```
BaseObject-->NodeStart-->SomeDateTime
```

and so on. In our current, custom implemented data handling, we "serialize" the complex objects in two levels, so, we have columns like

```
Id, Name, etc (in BaseObject)
```

and we also have

```
NodeStart_SomeDateTime
```

so we take sub-objects and take their properties, create columns and indexes as needed. IN this way, we can search for sub-objects properties and filter on that.

Complex objects in OrmLite are blobbed in JSON format, and that's nice, but I haven't seen any support for "native JSON" in OrmLite, so indexes can be created on properties inside blobbed JSON, as can be done with [Marten on Postgre](http://jasperfx.github.io/marten/).

My question is: Does ServiceStack plan to add support in its API for native JSON types in SQL database (MySQL!), so it can be indexed (via code) and searched using the APIs/LINQ etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no plan to provide a typed API for accessing non-standard JSON syntax.

You’d need to use [Custom SQL APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis) to execute any custom queries.

Comment: May I ask why? Isnt that pure greatness to add that, if supported by the db? Adding such support is probably the future, and would solve many issues and problems.

Comment: It’s a non standard proprietary extension that’s not supported in all RDMBS’s, doesn’t map intuitively to a Typed Expressions and there’s no demand for it.